# saving forms via TemplateView

Tags: django

I am trying to save forms via Post by TemplateView, but when def Post calls, forms are not saved.
using inline formset . Book Title is saved by Author,1 author can have multiple books .

Codes below are what I am using:

This is the view , Posting content of Inlineformset , if it is get , shows the form , if it is post it must save the data .
#view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,UpdateView
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Author,Book
from django.shortcuts import redirect
class BookView(TemplateView):

    template_name ="index.html"
   

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return self.render_preview(request)


    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):

        return self.save_book(request)

        
    def save_book(self,request,**kwargs):

        BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, fields=('title',),can_delete=False)
        author = Author.objects.get(name='John')
        formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('/')
        context = super(BookView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = formset

        return self.render_to_response(context)
        
                              

    def render_preview(self, request, **kwargs):

        BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, fields=('title',),can_delete=False)
        author = Author.objects.get(name='John')
        formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)
        context = super(BookView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = formset

        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

#Models
This is the models.py

```
# Create your models here.
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

index.html

```
<form action="" method="post" >
   
    <div class="html">
     
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for form in formset %}
    
        {{form }}

       
    
        {%endfor %}
    
    <button type="submit">save</button>

</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue not so long ago and I solved it a bit different than by using a FormSet (which I am not so familiar with), hope it helps you out:

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from Appname.models import Author, Book

class Author(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name']

class Book(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['author', 'title']
```

Views.py

```
class BookView(TemplateView):
    template_name ="index.html"
    author_form_class = Author

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(BookView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['author_form'] = self.author_form_class
    context['book_form'] = self.book_form_class
    
    return context

def post(self, request):
    author_form_class = Author(request.POST or None)
    book_form_class = Book(request.POST or None)

    if author_form_class.is_valid():
        author_form_class.save()
        return redirect('/')

    if book_form_class.is_valid():
        book_form_class.save()
        return redirect('/')
```

index.html

```
<form method="post">
    {{ csrf_token }}
    {{ author_form}}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```